# Can I implement compression in my Python Heroku App?

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gzip

I want to try and implement compression into my webapp, but the methods I use online just don't seem to work. .htaccess files dont work for my webapp, and all the python-flask libraries I download don't enable gzip.

Is there any way for me to implement compression into my web app?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to compress? Why can't you use the `gzip` Python extension?

Comment: @JohanL Which python extension? Thanks

Comment: Please read [ask]. What do you mean by "implement compression"?

Comment: I meant Python module.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290766/enabling-compression-on-heroku-using-python